# Show that, $2A+B=\zeta(3)$

Tags: integration

Show that,

$2A+B=\zeta(3)$, where

$$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{x}{e^x+1}\right)^2dx =A$$

$$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)^2dx =B$$

Where $\zeta(3) $it is known as an Apery's constant and had the value 
$\zeta(3)=1.202056...$

---

Using subsititution method,
Let $u=e^x+1$

$$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{x}{e^x+1}\right)^2dx=A$$

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2(u-1)}{(u+1)^2(u-1)}du=A$$
This look more harder than the original question.

I am stuck here, any help please? Also integration by part is making it more complicated it is. **Can anybody help to solve this for me.**
**Or do I have find a suitable integral transformation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly straightforward as I see it.
$$\begin{align}A=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac x{e^x+1}\right)^2dx&=\int_0^{\infty}\left[\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}+x^2\frac d{dx}\left(\frac1{e^x+1}\right)\right]dx\\
&=\left.\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}\right|_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2-2x}{e^x+1}dx\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2-2x}{e^x+1}dx\end{align}$$
Recall that
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}dx&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^ne^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}(-1)^ke^{-kx}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\Gamma(n+1)}{(k+1)^{n+1}}\\
&=\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right)n!\zeta(n+1)\end{align}$$
So
$$A=\left(1-\frac14\right)(2)\zeta(3)-2\left(1-\frac12\right)(1)\zeta(3)=\frac32\zeta(3)-\zeta(2)$$
Similarly,
$$\begin{align}B=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac x{e^x-1}\right)^2dx&=\int_0^{\infty}\left[\frac{-x^2}{e^x-1}-x^2\frac d{dx}\left(\frac1{e^x-1}\right)\right]dx\\
&=\left.\frac{-x^2}{e^x-1}\right|_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-x^2+2x}{e^x-1}dx\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-x^2+2x}{e^x-1}dx\end{align}$$
And again,
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}dx&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^ne^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}e^{-kx}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(k+1)^{n+1}}=n!\zeta(n+1)\end{align}$$
So
$$B=-(2)\zeta(3)+2(1)\zeta(2)=-2\zeta(3)+2\zeta(2)$$
Adding up,
$$2A+B=\zeta(3)$$